# Include JSON from Django Rest Framework in an HTML template

Tags: json, django, django-templates, django-rest-framework

I am trying to do something very simple but haven't found how to do it yet.

I have a model and an endpoint returning a JSON array reprenseting the instances of this model with Django Rest Framework. I want to include the JSON in an HTML template (for SEO and for fast initial data loading). Something like

```
<script>
    var data = {% json_from_django_rest_framework "mymodel" %};
</script>
```

Is there an easy way to do this? Should I just go a different way?

Comment: How do you want to render / create this template? Obviously, the DRF endpoint will deliver you some data (in this case in JSON). To statically render that JSON on the server, you could make a normal Django view that delivers your template. From within that view you could request the data from the DRF endpoint. I guess later on some Javascript on the frontend will take control over your webapp and this is why you need the REST API in the first place?

Comment: Yes I can serialize the JSON in python in the view. I was hopping there was a more straightforward way to do this in the template directly. Indeed, later on the javascript will make further requests to the REST endpoint.

Comment: Is your goal to avoid an additional view altogether or just to avoid having to create the same output that the DRF endpoint already provides in this additional view? In the latter case, you could use Django's [`resolve`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urlresolvers/#resolve) helper to reuse the JSON-output from DRF within your view and thus still keep it DRY. (I could provide an example for that)

Comment: The latter. Yes an example would be nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, here is an example of how to reuse the result from your api endpoint in a normal Django view by using Django's [`resolve`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urlresolvers/#resolve) function.

**views.py**

```
import json
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve
from django.views.generic.base import View    

class FooView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        # optional stuff in your view...

        ##
        # Resolving another Django view programmatically
        ##
        rev = '/path/to/api/endpoint/'  # or use reverse()
        view, vargs, vkwargs = resolve(rev)
        vkwargs['request'] = request
        res = view(*vargs, **vkwargs)

        c = Context({
            'data': json.dumps(res.data)
        })

        # Now the JSON serialized result from the API endpoint
        # will be available in the template variable data.
        return render(request, 'my-app/my-template.html', c)
```

**my-template.html**

```
<script>
    var data = {{ data }};
</script>
```

**Note 1:** Instead of hardcoding the path in `rev = '/path/to/api/endpoint/'` it is better to [`reverse()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) the url, but I left it out to remove that as a source for errors. If you are going this direction, here is [a list](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#usage) of the default url names provided by DRF

**Note 2:** The snippet would benefit from exception handling, like making sure that `res` returned 200, has the `data` property, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Another way of doing this, which gets around rendering the view.

In your views.py;

```python
class FooDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Foo
    template_name = 'foo/detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        bars = []
        for bar in self.object.bars.all():
            bars.append(BarSerializer(bar).data)

        kwargs['bars'] = JSONRenderer().render(bars)

        return super(FooDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

And in your template;

```html
<script>
    var bars = {{ bars|safe }};
</script>
```

It should really go without saying that you should pay attention to potential performance issues with this approach, ie.. perhaps it's best to paginate `bars`.

Comment: I much prefer this answer as it doesn't require you to create a view to the serializer if you don't intend the data to be exposed via a viewset